# Docker API returns 200 OK then 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: rest, sockets, http, docker

I am writing an API client for Docker. I understood from the documentation that the API is Restful/HTTP, yet if you connect to the local daemon you have to do it over the exposed **unix socket**.

It all seems to work, I open a socket, send an HTTP request (which respects the [specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html)), I receive the expected response, **but also a `400 BAD REQUEST` response follows immediately.**

Here is the request:

```
GET /info HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: application/json
```

And here is what I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Api-Version: 1.30
Content-Type: application/json
Docker-Experimental: false
Ostype: linux
Server: Docker/17.06.1-ce (linux)
Date: Thu, 01 Feb 2018 18:53:18 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

892
{"ID":"6MGE:35TO:BI..." ...}

0

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: close

400 Bad Request
```

First, I figured that there is a bug on my side and I am somehow sending 2 requests, but I [enabled debugging](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/#enable-debugging) and followed the logs with `sudo journalctl -fu docker.service` and there is exactly one request received... at least one is logged, the `GET /info`. I've also debugged the code and 1 single request is sent.

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Edit: here is the client's code:

```
        final StringBuilder hdrs = new StringBuilder();
        for(final Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers) {
            hdrs.append(header.getKey() + ": " + header.getValue())
                .append("\r\n");
        }
        final String request = String.format(
            this.template(), method, home, hdrs, this.readContent(content)
        );

        final UnixSocketChannel channel = UnixSocketChannel.open(
            new UnixSocketAddress(this.path)
        );
        final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
            Channels.newOutputStream(channel)
        );
        writer.print(request);
        writer.flush();

        final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
            Channels.newInputStream(channel)
        );
        CharBuffer result = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);
        reader.read(result);
        result.flip();
        System.out.println("read from server: " + result.toString());
```

Comment: Please show the code of your client. You claim that you are sending 1 request, but it certainly seems like that is not the case. Maybe you send some data to the socket after sending the proper request?

Comment: @Nebril Here it is: https://github.com/amihaiemil/docker-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amihaiemil/docker/UnixSocket.java#L146 ... that UnixSocketChannel is opened and the PrintWriter writes in it. Then, get the InputStream from it and read the response's content.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have an extra CRLF between headers and body.

```
 private String template() {
            final StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message
                .append("%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n")
                .append("Host: localhost").append("\r\n")
                .append("%s")
                .append("\r\n").append("\r\n") //one of these is superfluous, as each header line ends with "\r\n" itself 
                .append("%s");
            return message.toString();
}
```

Remove one `append("\r\n")` after headers and see what happens.

Comment: I already played with all those CRLFs. If I remove some of them, then the request won't work at all -- the Printer writes it and then the process just waits for the response's content which doesn't come; probably because the request is malformed... but I will try to do as you suggested as well, I'm not sure if I tried that :)

Comment: @amihaiemil any luck? I really wonder if that was the case. If not, you probably should file an issue in Docker.

Comment: nope, not yet, only later, tonight. Yes, I already filed an issue: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/215 ... And besides this 400 BAD REQUEST, it is also not clear to me why the content of the first response has 892 on the first line and only then the actual JSON... I think I'll also try to update Docker, maybe it will help.

Comment: I tried now, but it doesn't work. If I remove one of those CRLFs, the request just hangs, it keeps going and no response is received.

Comment: I also updated Docker to the latest version (17.12.0-ce) and the behaviour is still the same. Let's see if the guys respond on Github...

Comment: Apparently, it was because of \r\n line endings. I replaced them all with simple \n and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Initially, I thought the problem was with the line endings (that they should have been \n instead of \r\n). Turns out, the 400 BAD REQUEST occured because the `Connection: close` header was missing, while the Request made was being closed right after receiving the response.

More details [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/215#issuecomment-362939302).

Comment: No, it's both problems. `Connection: close` closes the HTTP connection after 1 request, but your request was still interpreted as 2 requests because of the double \r\n. Next time, better use a standard HTTP client as it will support all the stuff you forgot about in case Docker changes their API in a different standard-compliant way.

Comment: @Evert is right, and the regular line ending **is** `\r\n`, `n` alone is supported, but not always. By adding the `Connection: close` you fixed the problem because you tell the server to ignore the next requests, ignoring your garbage after this one, but that's not the real fix. By sending some stuff after the first request you were starting an HTTP pipeline.

Comment: Well, I can't tell what exactly is sent more? ``\r\n`` is the line ending required by the HTTP specification. If I remove that second line ending after the headers (``headers.trim()``) and leave out ``Connection:close``, the request just hangs, Docker does not respond. And I am not using a standard HTTP client because there is none that works over Unix Sockets... I did see an example which is using Apache HTTPClient somehow, but that is way too complicated. Besides, Apache doesn't offer me the interfaces I need for my library's architecture -- it is simply not object oriented.

Comment: What I think is sure, though, is that I need ``Connection: close``, since the stream to the unix socket is closed after each request.